# Redirecting subdomains to certain ports

Tags: dns, subdomain, ip-address, portforwarding

I am the proud owner of my very first server(registered with GoDaddy).

This machine, like most, has an IP. Let's pretend my server IP is 255.255.255.255.

I wish to host multiple servers on this tower: Minecraft, TeamSpeak, Feed the Beast, Garry's Mod, and my website. *(Don't worry, I don't get much traffic.)*

What I would like is a setup as such:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|Service   |Subdomain           |Actual IP            |
-------------------------------------------------------
|Website   |digiduncan.com      |255.255.255.255:80   |
|Minecraft |mc.digiduncan.com   |255.255.255.255:25565|
|FTB       |ftb.digiduncan.com  |255.255.255.255:9001 |
|TeamSpeak |ts3.digiduncan.com  |255.255.255.255:9987 |
|Garrys Mod|gmod.digiduncan.com |255.255.255.255:27015|
-------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I do this with DNS, or other GoDaddy domain manager options?

Answer (score 0):

BLUF:  You can't manipulate port traffic like that through DNS

As far as I know, you can not do this with DNS.  DNS is for name to ip mapping.  To specify a port like you are trying to do, that happens on the application that are trying to connect to your server.  For example, someone connecting to your minecraft server would have to know to connect on port 25565 at that IP address (which can be set on the minecraft client connecting in).  If you are going to want to do this through DNS, then you are going to have to have multiple IP addresses (which I'm assuming you are not wanting to do this).

I'm not a boundary device guy but maybe, MAYBE some kind of port redirection on your end with your firewall to your server (network firewall, not host) based on the provided URL.  Or have a web service on the server to create a connection back to the client based on URL provide.  Just spit balling here.  I'm not sure how that would (if it would) work.